# Divide full name into first and last when middle name is present

Tags: sas

I wanted to see if this was doable in SAS. I have a dataset of the members of congress and want to split full name into first and last. However, occasionally they seem to list their middle initial or name. It is from a .txt file.

```
Norton, Eleanor Holmes [D-DC] 16 0 440 288 0 
Cohen, Steve [D-TN] 15 0 320 209 0 
Schakowsky, Janice D. [D-IL] 6 0 289 186 0 
McGovern, James P. [D-MA] 8 1 252 139 0 
Clarke, Yvette D. [D-NY] 7 0 248 166 0 
Moore, Gwen [D-WI] 2 3 244 157 1 
Hastings, Alcee L. [D-FL] 13 1 235 146 0 
Raskin, Jamie [D-MD] 8 1 232 136 0 
Grijalva, Raul M. [D-AZ] 9 1 228 143 0 
Khanna, Ro [D-CA] 4 0 223 150 0
```

Comment: Yes, it's doable, start looking at the `SCAN()` function and see how you get on. The problem with these sorts of tasks is that there are sometimes exceptions to any 'rules'

Comment: Also you could use perl regular expressions https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n13as9vjfj7aokn1syvfyrpaj7z5.htm
But first as said by mjsqu you need rules to define what is first name and what is last name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day,

SAS is a bit clunky when it comes to Strings. However it can be done. As other have mentioned, it's the logic defined, which is the really hard part.

Begin with some raw data...

```
data begin; 
input raw_str $ 1-100; 
cards;
  Norton, Eleanor Holmes [D-DC] 16 0 440 288 0 
  Cohen, Steve [D-TN] 15 0 320 209 0 
  Schakowsky, Janice D. [D-IL] 6 0 289 186 0 
  McGovern, James P. [D-MA] 8 1 252 139 0 
  Clarke, Yvette D. [D-NY] 7 0 248 166 0 
  Moore, Gwen [D-WI] 2 3 244 157 1 
  Hastings, Alcee L. [D-FL] 13 1 235 146 0 
  Raskin, Jamie [D-MD] 8 1 232 136 0 
  Grijalva, Raul M. [D-AZ] 9 1 228 143 0 
  Khanna, Ro [D-CA] 4 0 223 150 0 
; run;
```

first I select the leading names till the first bracket.

count the number of strings

```
data names; 
  set begin; 
  names_only = scan(raw_str,1,'[');
  Nr_of_str = countw(names_only,' ');
run;
```

Assumption: First sting is the last name.

If there are only 2 strings, the first and last are pretty easy with scan and substring:

```
data names2; 
  set names; 
  if Nr_of_str = 2 then do; 
    last_name = scan(names_only, 1, ' '); 

    _FirstBlank = find(names_only, ' ');
    first_name = strip(substr(names_only, _FirstBlank));
  end; 
run;
```

Assumption: there are only 3 strings. 
approach 1. Middle name has dot in it. Filter it out. 
approach 2. Middle name is shorter than real name:

```
data names3; 
  set names2; 
  if Nr_of_str > 2 then do; 
    last_name = scan(names_only, 1, ' '); /*this should still hold*/

    _FirstBlank = find(names_only, ' '); /*Substring approach */
    first_name = strip(substr(names_only, _FirstBlank));


   second_str = scan(names_only, 2, ' ');
   third_str = scan(names_only, 3, ' ');

   if  find(second_str,'.') = 0 then   /*1st approch */
    first_name =  scan(names_only, 2, ' ');
  else 
    first_name =  scan(names_only, 3, ' ');


   if  len(second_str) > len(second_str) then   /*2nd approch */
    first_name =  second_str;
  else 
    first_name =  third_str;


  end; 
run;
```

For more see about [subsring](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/66845/HTML/default/viewer.htm#imlug_langref_sect455.htm) and [scan](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000214639.htm):

Comment: According your assumption George Herbert Walker Bush will become Herbert Bush.

Comment: @Lee True enough. I'm not an American so worked with data given. (And was far too lazy to find whole data) Oh well, the hard part is to define the logic how to find fist name. My answer was about technical side. Good point overall.